# CORS not working on apollo-server-express

Tags: express, graphql, apollo

**Package:** apollo-server-express

**Version:** `v2.6.0`

**Issue:** CORS settings aren't taking effect.

**Reported to Apollo?:** Yes, [Issue 3058](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3058)

**Description:** From our react client, we started sending `apollographql-client-name` & `apollographql-client-version` headers for [better client awareness](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/platform/client-awareness/#setup) in Apollo Engine.

`Access to fetch at 'https://something.com/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field apollographql-client-name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

We receive above `CORS` error. We enabled `cors` on Apollo Server through express middleware by passing `cors: true`. For some reason, this changes are not making any difference. We continue to receive above error.

```
const server: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
...
...
});

const app: Application = express();

server.applyMiddleware({
   app,
   cors: true,
   path: '/graphql',
});
```

- We have `nginx` sitting in front and it does receive request and forwards to Apollo Server.
- `cors: true` enables everything by default?
- We tried being very specific but that didn't help either.

```
cors: {
   origin: true,
   allowedHeaders: ['Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'apollographql-client-name']
},
```

Any inputs and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Issue is resolved.

We had kubernetes ingress layer on top of our `Apollo Server` and that's what was causing changes not to reflect. After we enabled `cors` on nginx ingress, we were able to make successful calls.